# With Enzyme, how can I test changing the number of children?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have a `<Parent/>` component, and I'd like use Enzyme to test its behavior when I add/remove/change its `<Child/>` components. For example, changing

```js
<Parent>
  <Child />
</Parent>
```

to

```js
<Parent>
  <Child />
  <Child />
</Parent>
```

I am working with a 3rd party library that manipulates the DOM, so I need to keep track of the children to keep React and the library in sync.

I tried calling `mount` multiple times, although the two `mount` calls create two different instances. For example,

```js
let constructorCalls = 0;
let Parent = class extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    constructorCalls += 1;
  }
  render() { return <span />; }
}

mount(<Parent />);
mount(<Parent />);

// Now, constructorCalls = 2
```

Calling `mount` twice creates two different Parents and two different constructor calls, therefore it does not behave like React would and do nothing if the rendered component does not change.

So, how can I "re-mount" a component with different children using Enzyme?

Comment: Aren't your children component changing when events are triggered (for example onClick).

Answer (score 0):

I still can't find an answer with Enzyme, so here's an Enzyme-ish solution.

It doesn't like Enzyme has this functionality, so I accomplished it by in-lining a wrapper Component and change the number of children by passing props to the wrapper. (note I'm using ES6 classes)

```js
const WrapperComponent = class extends React.Component{
  static defaultProps = {
    n: 1
  }
  render() {
    if (this.props.n > 1) {
      return (
        <Parent>
          <Child />
          <Child />
        </Parent>
      );
    }
    return (
      <Parent>
        <Child />
      </Parent>
    );
  }
}

const wrapper = mount(<WrapperComponent/>);

// ... test the state of Parent with one child

wrapper.setProps({ n: 2});

// ... test the state of Parent with two children
```